# PyQt5/PySide2 процессы

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, интерфейс, pyside2

По фану решил делать антивирус. Возникла проблема. Когда я запускаю сканирование у меня тормозит интерфейс. Пробовал запускать в процессе threading, но всеравно интерфейс подлагивает и крашится...Подскажите плиз как можно искоренить эту проблему.

```
    def scan_btn_start(self):
        full = self.ui.scanning_choose_btn_full.isChecked()
        folder = self.ui.scanning_choose_btn_folder.isChecked()
        file = self.ui.scanning_choose_btn_file.isChecked()

        if full:
            path = 'C:/'

        elif folder:
            path = easygui.diropenbox()
            status = 'folder'
        elif file:
            path = easygui.fileopenbox()
            status = 'file'
        else:
            path = None
            status = None

        if path != None:
            self.progress_bar_scan.set_value(0)
            threading.Thread(target=ScanVirusAll().scan_all, args=(self.progress_bar_scan, status, path)).start()
```

```
    def scan_all(self, progress_bar, status, path):
        max_threads = 15

        if status == 'folder':
            if path != None:
                all_paths = self.files_get(path)
                count_all_paths = len(all_paths)
                count_success_paths = 0

                for file_path in all_paths:
                    try:
                        while True:
                            if threading.active_count() < max_threads:
                                threading.Thread(target=self.scanning, args=(file_path,)).start()
                                count_success_paths += 1

                                ## ==> Заполнение прогресс бара
                                progress_bar.set_value(round(count_success_paths / count_all_paths * 100))

                                break
                            else:
                                time.sleep(0.0001)
                    except Exception as er:
                        print(er)

                print(f'All paths: {count_all_paths}')
                print(f"Scanned files: {count_success_paths}")
                print(f'Viruses detected: {len(self.bad_files)}\n\n')
                for f in self.bad_files: print(f"INFECTED - {f}")
```

Вот видео с самой проблемой - vimple.co/46e2cd421fc9440c9f639b190e21d543

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Можете написать в телеграм, я прямо там скину вам архив с кодом, там и расскажу что да как.                     Тг: @dimflix_official